# PHPMailer E-mail with SMTP recognizes as Junk in hotmail

Tags: php, email, smtp

I know this has been answered before based on this topic

[PHPmailer sending mail to spam in hotmail. how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899768/phpmailer-sending-mail-to-spam-in-hotmail-how-to-fix)

But i have tried it recently and still, it goes to Junk for hotmail. Perhaps there might be new required headers to send mail through SMTP Authentication. I have used the same code as of what the article above used. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hotmail's the worse for this. Even after marking legitimate messages as "not spam", they're still sent to spam. This, containing perfectly valid headers.

Comment: Other websites though that sends automated e-mails were able to send it in my inbox. That keeps my hope of a way to make this possible with the PHPMailer Script.

Comment: I suggest you look at what they're using for their headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Who is hosting this application? I had the same issue for one of my clients on Godaddy and found out even if I have authenticated SMTP, I can't still send emails or when it does send it goes to spam.

Just make sure require ports are open.

Comment: So the required port for SMTP server is 25, which is open. Are there else in which it should be open? what are the ports and what do they serve as for the sending of e-mail with SMTP?

Comment: 25 is fine but check if hosting provider is allowing you to send emails & authenticate via their server

Comment: So did you resolve this?